# Ldap bind message in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ldap

I have a question. Currently I am working with ldap connection.

I have no issue with ldap connection as I am using manual ldap codes. My connection with ldap is success.

All seems good when I enter the correct username and password. I have problem when I enter wrong password, the page will show "ErrorException ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Invalid credentials" ang the page also shows all login function codes.

How can I show the proper error message without the page show ErrorException? for information, I am not using any ldap installation framework.

example my codes:

```
public function process_login(Request $request)
{
  $username = $request->username;
  $password = $request->password;

  $ldaphost= "xxxx";
  $ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldaphost) or die("That LDAP-URI was not parseable");
  $ldap_credential= 'uid='.$username.',cn=xxx';
  $ldappass = $password;

if ($ldapconn) 
{  
  $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldap_credential, $ldappass);

  if ($ldapbind) {
     return redirect()->route('dashboard');
  }
  else
      {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg', 'Wrong Password/Username']);
      }
}
}
```

login.blade:

```
@if($errors->any())
        <h4>{{$errors->first()}}</h4>
@endif
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I, along with many others, ran into this same problem with LDAP authentication from PHP.  Totally agree, it is pretty sloppy to show those errors.  Believe it or not, among the most common solutions is to just silence the bind process with the standard PHP`@`, to avoid showing the unwanted error message.

In your case, something like:

```
if (@ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldap_credential, $ldappass)) {
   return redirect()->route('dashboard');
}
else
{
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg', 'Wrong Password/Username']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you really much. It works. I also tried using adldap2 framework but its not working. maybe I am not familiar and no one can guide how to use it. once again, thank you :)

Comment: It is bad habit to use error suppression to not show any messages on the website...

Comment: As a general rule, yes.  But when you specifically do not wish to supply those error messages to your users in favor our your own error handling, then it is perfectly acceptable.   Tailoring the message is what he's after.  To your point - not showing *any* errors is certainly not a good idea.  Thus his display of a more specific error.

Answer (score 0):

When you see messages from PHP on your website that usually means that your PHP installation is misconfigured.

On production websites the PHP.ini file (find the location of your PHP.ini file using a phpinfo-page) should have `display_errors` and `display_startup_errors` set to `false` but `error_log` to euther `syslog` or to a path to an error-log file.

Also you should not set `error_reporting` to 0 as you will then have a hard time debugging your production site.

If you don't want the messages from `ldap_bind` show up in your error log either you should use `set_error_handler` to set an error handler that removes specifically this one message, possibly just for this one function call, and reset the original error handler.

Especially in case of `ldap_bind` you will otherwise possibly have issues debugging what happened as that usually is the first command that actually opens a connection to the server so a lot of connection issues will come up in the messages from this functiin. Which you will never see when you silence every message from the function using the `@`